# flash: after loadSound finishes loading, song plays from start again

Tags: flash, audio, actionscript, actionscript-2

i have this simple code

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
mySound.loadSound("128kbps_stereo.mp3", true);
```

it does load the sound and plays it. however, the song plays for a little while and then starts over again! so the sound plays twice in a short period of time for some reason

i investigated this a little bit and it turns out it plays the song again automatically after the mp3 has finished loading and i don't know why

i've tried creating a blank mySound.onLoad function and still nothing. i don't call mySound.play() from absolutely anywhere! i don't know why this happens

could someone enlighten me?

EDIT: fixed this now... look in the comments for the mistake

Comment: You must be using something other than Flash's native [Sound](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html) class, as that class has no method named `loadSound()`. Can you clarify what the Sound class is that you're using?

Comment: @SunilD. user1916182 is talking about actionscript 2, that's why he uses this function

Comment: Have you tried to start the sound only when it's loaded ? mySound.loadSound("name.mp3", false) and mySound.start in the onLoad function... ?

Comment: yep, i did try to mySound.loadSound("128kbps_stereo.mp3, false) and start in the onloadfunction but then i won't get the streaming audio...

i have this weird feeling that it's something with cache, but i am hopeless in this. has anyone else really not ever experienced this?

Comment: to make a long story short: been publishing a backup swf file and copying an old index.swf file to the server ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to make a long story short: been publishing a backup swf file and copying an old index.swf file to the server ...

apologies to everyone